HR000057: Failed to execute statement
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: h2
    reactive:
      url: vertx-reactive:h2:mem:jokesdb
    username: sa
    password: ""
    jdbc: false
  hibernate-orm:
    database:
      generation: drop-and-create  # Use "update" for production
  hibernate-orm-log-sql: true

# Disable PostgreSQL if enabled
quarkus:
  hibernate-orm:
    dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect

  devservices:
    enabled: false  # Disables dev services which may start PostgreSQL by default
    quarkus:
      log:
        category:
          "org.hibernate.SQL":  # Logs the SQL queries
            level: DEBUG
          "org.hibernate.orm":   # Logs Hibernate-related actions
            level: DEBUG


package org.com.entity;

import io.quarkus.hibernate.reactive.panache.PanacheEntityBase;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import java.util.UUID;

@Entity
public class Joke extends PanacheEntityBase {

    @Id
    public String id;
    public String question;
    public String answer;

    public Joke() {
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public Joke(String question, String answer) {
        this();
        this.question = question;
        this.answer = answer;
    }
}

getting below error
2024-10-21 15:27:39,010 ERROR [org.hib.rea.errors] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-0) HR000057: Failed to execute statement [select * from information_schema.sequences]: could not execute query : java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: getsockopt: localhost/127.0.0.1:5432


Not sure but in your yaml config you have to quarkus top level entries - did you try to merge them? Could be that the second one wins over the first and then you will not have any database configured.
